# Combine local packages directories

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm running Cygwin64 on Windows 10. Usually I use only one particular mirror in my country. As it happened, I had to go abroad. I needed to install a package, so using Cygwin's setup.exe, I change the mirror to another mirror.

I see that each mirror has its own directory under `C:\Cygwin64\pkgs` (that's the directory I told Cygwin to store its packages in).

Is it safe to combine the mirrors' directories into one (i.e., copy the 'temporary' mirror's directory tree onto my 'regular' mirror directory)?

---

**Edit:** To illustrate, this is the layout of the directories:

```
C:\Cygwin64
+-pkgs
  +-http%3a%2f%2fdownload.nus.edu.sg%2fmirror%2fcygwin%2f
  | +-x86_64
  |   +-release
  |     +-_update_info_dir
  |     +-(many per-package directories)
  +-http%3a%2f%2fkambing.ui.ac.id%2fcygwin%2f
  | +-x86_64
  |   +-release
  |     +-_autorebase
  |     +-_update_info_dir
  |     +-(many per-package directories)
```

I want to copy everything under

```
C:\Cygwin64\pkgs\http%3a%2f%2fdownload.nus.edu.sg%2fmirror%2fcygwin%2f\x86_64\release
```

into

```
C:\Cygwin64\pkgs\http%3a%2f%2fkambing.ui.ac.id%2fcygwin%2f\x86_64\release
```

and delete the former directory.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'safe'?.  2) It would be easy to try it and see.

Comment: 1) Will the cygwin `setup.exe` dies if it no longer finds the "download.nus.edu.sg" directory. Or, it will get confused horribly. 2) Yeah, I think I'll do that. Would be interesting... I'll post the result as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The download directory is just a cache of a particular mirror in a certain time. As all the mirrors are copy of the primary the full updated content is the same, so no problem to copy the most recent on top of another one.

You can also completely cancel the caches. The files are only needed if you need to reinstall from local.